# Biblatex authoryear-ibid: Specific Changes in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

Firstly, thank you tex.stackexchange for being the best TeX-Reference on the web. I have been using the archives for months now and could always find answers to my questions.

But now I am stuck:

I'm using `biblatex` with the `authoryear-ibid` style. I need some specific changes in my bibliography.

At the moment an `@incollection`-entry prints like this:

> Einstein, Albert (1929). »Using LaTeX«. In: The Latex User's Guide. Edited by Stephen Hawkins. New York: Publisher, p. 15-40. URL: http:\\en.wikipedia.org.

But I also have to reference the `@collection` which prints like this:

> Hawkins, Stephen, ed. (1929). The Latex User's Guide. New York: Publisher. URL: http:\\en.wikipedia.org.

Now the 1st problem: The fact that the publisher, address and URL are printed in the `@incollection`-entry makes my bibliography artificially and unnecessarily long.

What I want to have instead would be:

> Einstein, Albert (1929). »Using LaTeX«. In: The Latex User's Guide. Edited by Stephen Hawkins, p. 15-40.

2nd Problem: when the editor also was an author in the same `@collection` everything is printed twice, which also makes the bibliography artificially long. At the moment it prints like this

> Hawkins, Stephen, ed. (1929a). The Latex User's Guide. New York: Publisher. URL: http:\\en.wikipedia.org.
>
> --- (1929b). »Understanding LaTeX«. In: The Latex User's Guide. Edited by Stephen Hawkins. New York: Publisher, p. 1-15. URL: http:\\en.wikipedia.org.

But what I would prefer is that it prints something like this instead:

> Hawkins, Stephen, ed. (1929a). The Latex User's Guide. New York: Publisher. URL: http:\\en.wikipedia.org.
>
> --- (1929b). »Understanding LaTeX«. Edited by same in: The Latex User's Guide, p. 1-15.

(In German it would be:)

> Hawkins, Stephens (1929b). »Understanding LaTeX«. *In ders.:* The Latex User's Guide, S. 1-15.

How can I make that happen?

Thank you very much

EDIT:

Mininmal Working Example (compiled with xelatex & biber)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
            style=authoryear-ibid,
            backend=biber,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=none,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=2,
            ]{biblatex}
            
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{hawkins.1923,
    editor  = "Hawkins, Stephen",
    title   = "The Latex User's Guide",
    year    = "1923",
    publisher = "Publisher",
    address = "New York",
    url = "en.wikipedia.org",
}
@incollection{hawkins.1923b,
    author = "Hawkins, Stephen",
    title = "Understanding LaTeX",
    crossref = "hawkins.1923",
    pages = "1-15",
}

@incollection{einstein.1923,
    author = "Einstein, Albert",
    title = "Using LaTeX",
    crossref = "hawkins.1923",
    pages = "16-45",
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname} 

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be a disadvantage of `biblatex` in comparison with `bibtex`. While it is certainly possible to modify things as you wish, there doesn't seem to be any standard option or feature allowing this. (This is one of two features I really feel the lack of with `biblatex`.) I am currently hoping that your question will show I'm wrong about this but I think you will get redefinitions. That's OK but it would be nice if there were a simple option covering this kind of feature. You should edit your answer to include a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem which people can compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much of this problem can be solved by altering the inheritance of fields from the cross-referenced `@collection` entry to its children `@incollection` entries. Note that the default inheritance (described in the appendix of the biblatex manual) can be changed only with biber.

The rest can be handled by tracking the `editor` names between bibliography items. Here this is done by re-purposing `\indexnames` and comparing the `hash` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% just for demo
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{abbreviate=false}

\NewBibliographyString{same}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{same = {same}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{same = {ders}}

% @incollection gets editor not publisher, address, url from @collection
\DeclareDataInheritance{collection}{incollection}{
  \inherit{editor}{editor}
  \noinherit{publisher}
  \noinherit{location}
  \noinherit{url}
}

% collect editor name hash
\newcommand*{\editorhash}{}
\newcommand*{\lasteditorhash}{}
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{gethash}{\xappto{\editorhash}{\thefield{hash},}}

% replace recurrent editor list with same string
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \let\lasteditorhash\editorhash
  \renewcommand*{\editorhash}{}%
  \indexnames[gethash]{editor}%
  \ifdefstrequal{\lasteditorhash}{\editorhash}
    {\xapptobibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}
       {\setunit{\addspace}\bibstring{same}\clearname{editor}}{}{}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Collection{hawkins:ed,
  editor       = {Hawkins, Stephen},
  title        = {The Latex User's Guide},
  year         = 1923,
  publisher    = {Publisher},
  url          = {en.wikipedia.org},
  address      = {New York},
}
@InCollection{hawkins,
  author       = {Hawkins, Stephen},
  title        = {Understanding LaTeX},
  pages        = {1-15},
  crossref     = {hawkins:ed},
}
@InCollection{einstein,
  author       = {Einstein, Albert},
  title        = {Using LaTeX},
  pages        = {16-45},
  crossref     = {hawkins:ed},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname,biblatex-examples} 

\begin{document}
\nocite{hawkins:ed,hawkins,einstein,nietzsche:ksa,nietzsche:ksa1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I didn't bother to reverse the "In..." and "Edited by..." fragments when the `editor` is recurrent, but you can do so by hooking code into the `in:` bibliography macro.

Comment: That's so much more elegant than my solution above. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, to achieve this there is quite a lot to be done.

This first portion of code makes sure to move the editor before the title for `@inbook` and `@incollection`.

```
\newbibmacro*{ineditor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{author}% if author equals editor, print idem
      {\printtext{\bibstring{idem\thefield{gender}}}%
       \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}%
      {\printnames{editor}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}%
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{inauthor/editor+others/translator+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    not test {\ifnameundef{bookauthor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
     }
       {\usebibmacro{ineditor+others}}
       {%\usebibmacro{translator+others}
       }}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }
  {\usebibmacro{ineditor+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
%       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }%
  {\typeout{replaced \usebibmacro{byeditor+others} by \usebibmacro{ineditor+others} in BibliographyDriver{incollection}}}
  {\typeout{failed to replace \usebibmacro{byeditor+others} by \usebibmacro{ineditor+others} in BibliographyDriver{incollection}}}%


\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }
  {\usebibmacro{inauthor/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }%
  {}
  {\typeout{failed to replace \usebibmacro{byeditor+others} by \usebibmacro{ineditor+others} in BibliographyDriver{inbook}}}%
```

The following shortens the `crossref` for `@in....` entries if the `crossref`'d entry in the bibliography already.

```
\newcommand{\shortxref}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    }
    {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}%
    }%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
      {\printfield{isbn}}
      {}%
    }
    {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
      {}
      {\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
        {\printfield{isbn}}
        {}}%
    }%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{series+number}}%
    }%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}
}
\shortxref{incollection}
\shortxref{inbook}
```

I did not get rid of the URL here, but this can be done via

```
\xpatchbibdriver{#1}
  {\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}
  {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  }%
  {}
  {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
            style=authoryear-ibid,
            backend=biber,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=none,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=2,
            ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{hawkins.1923,
    editor  = "Hawkins, Stephen",
    title   = "The Latex User's Guide",
    year    = "1923",
    publisher = "Publisher",
    address = "New York",
    url = "en.wikipedia.org",
    series = {A Series},
    number  = {6},
}
@incollection{hawkins.1923b,
    author = "Hawkins, Stephen",
    title = "Understanding LaTeX",
    crossref = "hawkins.1923",
    pages = "1-15",
}

@incollection{einstein.1923,
    author = "Einstein, Albert",
    title = "Using LaTeX",
    crossref = "hawkins.1923",
    pages = "16-45",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbibmacro*{ineditor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\ifnamesequal{editor}{author}% if author equals editor, print idem
      {\printtext{\bibstring{idem\thefield{gender}}}%
       \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}%
      {\printnames{editor}}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}%
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{inauthor/editor+others/translator+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    not test {\ifnameundef{bookauthor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
     }
       {\usebibmacro{ineditor+others}}
       {%\usebibmacro{translator+others}
       }}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }
  {\usebibmacro{ineditor+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
%       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }%
  {\typeout{replaced \usebibmacro{byeditor+others} by \usebibmacro{ineditor+others} in BibliographyDriver{incollection}}}
  {\typeout{failed to replace \usebibmacro{byeditor+others} by \usebibmacro{ineditor+others} in BibliographyDriver{incollection}}}%


\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }
  {\usebibmacro{inauthor/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  }%
  {}
  {\typeout{failed to replace \usebibmacro{byeditor+others} by \usebibmacro{ineditor+others} in BibliographyDriver{inbook}}}%

\newcommand{\shortxref}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
    }
    {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}%
    }%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
      {\printfield{isbn}}
      {}%
    }
    {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
      {}
      {\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
        {\printfield{isbn}}
        {}}%
    }%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {\ifentryinbib{\thefield{crossref}}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{series+number}}%
    }%
    {}
    {\typeout{failed to shorten crossref in #1}}
}
\shortxref{incollection}
\shortxref{inbook}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **Beautiful thank you!**

I added your alterations via `\input{citestyle}` in the preamble. 
And you also have a small mistake in the `URL` part: you commented out two `}`

Comment: @Paul Thanks for catching that, it should be fixed now.

Comment: added feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues?state=open