# How to output ISSN field for specific biblatex types (@inbook)?

Tags: biblatex

The below MWE, compiled with `pdflatex test.tex && biber test && pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  style=ieee,
  isbn=true, % should also be for issn?
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% in ieee.bbx, \printfield{issn} done only for @article; standard.bbx also has it for @periodical
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article {myinprocs,
  author = {Someb Authorb},
  title = {{Testing the title of inproceedings}},
  pages={123--127},
  year={2010},
  issn = {2341-2341},
  url = {http://example.com/inproc.pdf},
}
@inbook {myinbook,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {{Testing the title of inbook}},
  url = {http://example.com/inbook.pdf},
  publisher={Some Publisher},
  pages={123--127},
  editor = {Some Editor},
  edition = {1},
  volume = {2},
  series = {My Series},
  issn = {1234-1234},
  booktitle = {This Booktitle},
  address = {Someplace},
  year={2008},
  month={jun},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Testing inbook: \cite{myinbook}, \cite{myinprocs}

\printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```

... output this:

[image: test.png]

Only the `@article` type outputs the ISSN field, while it is not output for the `@inbook` type. I've realized this is because the biblatex style `ieee.bbx` only does `\printfield{issn}` for the `@article` type.

How can I instruct biblatex to print the ISSN field also for the `@inbook` type - hopefully with the same style it is output in `@article` (e.g. the word "ISSN" being typeset with small caps)?

Comment: Sorry, but how can an entry `inbook` contain a ISSN field? ISBN for the book is ok, but ISSN?

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B - it's a reference I've downloaded from somewhere which was formatted as `inbook` (possibly wrongly), now it turns out that book actually has ISSN, so I wanted to include that without changing the downloaded reference too much. Anyways, I managed to solve this using `\xpatchbibdriver` as in  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160152/biblatex-authoryear-ibid-specific-changes-in-bibliography - at a later time, I might post a proper answer (but if someone posts an answer earlier, I'll accept that instead)... Cheers!

Comment: Books usually have a *ISBN*, that's why i am so confused. In fact, `@article`  and `@periodical` are the only types that support a `issn` field.

Comment: @Johannes_B - yeah, I see that now; although I've seen some PhD theses that have had both ISSN and ISBN...

Comment: Wikipedia quote: *An ISBN might be assigned for particular issues of a periodical, in addition to the ISSN code for the periodical as a whole. An ISSN, unlike the ISBN code, is an anonymous identifier associated with a periodical title, containing no information as to the publisher or its location.* I don't know your entry, but putting the isbn (if available) might be better.

Comment: btw: Do not blindly trust those downloadable bib-entries, especially when using `biblatex`. Due to its verious fields, no machine can parse a bibtex-conform entry to a real useful `biblatex`-conform entry. So adjustments will almost always be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the reservations expressed by some commenters here, it is not particularly unusual for a book to have both an ISBN and ISSN.  Many self-contained scholarly books are issued as part of a series, often with the individual entries getting assigned a specific "volume" number.  The book will generally bear a unique ISBN, as well as an ISSN shared by all books in the series.  An example of such a series would be Springer's [Lecture Notes in Computer Science](https://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-0-0-0) (ISSN 0302-9743).

The `xpatch` package can be used to patch the various Biblatex entry types so that both the ISSN and ISBN are displayed.  Here's an example (with optimizations courtesy of [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282118/22603)):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=book,inbook,collection,incollection,proceedings,inproceedings\do{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{\next}
    {{\printfield{isbn}}}
    {{\printfield{issn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{isbn}}}
    {}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Getting Biblatex to sensibly output the volume number also requires some work.  Due to how `standard.bbx` handles `volume` entries, I find it more convenient to use the `number` field, and to define the `series+number` bibmacro as follows:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,collection,incollection,proceedings,inproceedings]%
  {number}{\bibstring{volume}~#1 \bibstring{ofseries}}
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{series}%
  \newunit%
}
```

Using these two tricks together, if you have a Biblatex entry such as

```
@book{
  author = {Gary Gnu},
  series = {Zoological Investigations},
  number = 9876,
  title  = {All About Gnus},
  year   = 1978,
  issn   = {1234-5678},
  isbn   = {978-1-56619-909-4},
}
```

it will appear as something like the following in your bibliography:

> Gnu, Gary (1978).  *All About Gnus*.  Vol. 9876 of Zoological Investigations.  ISSN: 1234-5678.  ISBN: 978-1-56619-909-4.

Comment: LNCS "books" are not really books. They are proceedings. Anyway, this discussion is quite off-topic here.

Comment: They're "books" in the usual sense of the word.  In Biblatex parlance, yes, you should use `@proceedings` for them.  Regardless, what I said about books (in either sense of the word) having ISSNs is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `biblatex`, `@article` and `@periodical` are the only types that support a *issn* field. ISSN is the acronym for *International Standard Serial Number*.

> In contrast to serials in general, a periodical has been defined as "A serial publication with its own distinctive title, containing a mix of articles ... by more than one contributor, issued ... at regular stated intervals of less than a year, without prior decision as to when the final issue will appear." This includes magazines and journals, but not proceedings or newspapers. ([Wikipedia - Serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_%28publishing%29))

Books on the other hand have an ISBN (International Standard Book Number), which is unique with respect of authorship and the like.

> ISSN and ISBN codes are similar in concept, where ISBNs are assigned to individual books. For particular issues of a periodical an ISBN might be assigned in addition to the ISSN code for the periodical as a whole. ([Psychology Wikia](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number))

That is indeed often seen for dissertations that are published as a title in a university periodical (*Research at Duckburg university*), but as they are still independent works, an additional ISBN is assigned.

---

In conclusion, use judgement to decide which information to place where. When downloading bib-entries from a website, double check if the information is correct.