# Efficiently applying the same patch to several bibdrivers

Tags: biblatex, expansion, foreach, xpatch

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282114/22603) to a question about getting Biblatex to print the ISSN field for books, I suggest a solution which uses the `\xpatchbibdriver` command of the `xpatch` package:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
  {\printfield{isbn}}
}{%
  {\printfield{issn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{isbn}}
}{}{}
```

A problem with my answer is that the patch needs to be applied separately for each book-like bibliography type (book, collection, proceedings, incollection, inproceedings, etc.).

Is there a nicer way to patch all the entries at once?  I'm vaguely familiar with the `\foreach` command of the `pgffor` package, but the following naïve usage of it doesn't work, probably because it `\i` doesn't get expanded before getting passed to `\xpatchbibdriver`:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \i in {incollection,proceedings,book,inproceedings}{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{\i}{%
    {\printfield{isbn}}
  }{%
    {\printfield{issn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{isbn}}
  }{}{}
}
```

Is there a way I can force the expansion of `\i`?  Do I need an `\expandafter` in here somewhere?  (Alternatively, is there an even better way of doing what I'm doing without using `pgffor` and/or `xpatch`?)

Comment: A starter document would be nice, instead fragments of code ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `\xpatchbibdriver` builds a command name with `\csname...\endcsname`, the `\i` macro *is* expanded

The patch is not performed because `\foreach` does its workings in a group and so the patch will disappear at the end. Use `\@for`:

```
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=incollection,proceedings,book,inproceedings\do{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{\next}
    {{\printfield{isbn}}}
    {{\printfield{issn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{isbn}}}
    {}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

With `etoolbox` features:

```
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {{\printfield{isbn}}}
    {{\printfield{issn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{isbn}}}
    {}{}%
}
\docsvlist{incollection,proceedings,book,inproceedings}
```

With `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\massxpatchbibdriver}{mmmmm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \xpatchbibdriver{##1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\massxpatchbibdriver{incollection,proceedings,book,inproceedings}
  {{\printfield{isbn}}}
  {{\printfield{issn}\newunit\newblock\printfield{isbn}}}
  {}{}
```

Comment: Thanks; I've used this to update the answer mentioned in my question.